# Is there a solution for LIKE searches whose field have spaces at the end?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, we have an MS SQL Server database.  The database has evolved over time.    I am guessing that some fields used to be `CHAR(<somenumber>)` and are now `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`.  As a result, some of the data has spaces on the end.

Our app gives the option of searching for Exact/EndsWith/BeginsWith/Contains options.  The resulting SQL looks like this:

```
Select * from Customers where CustName LIKE 'Concord Elementary School'
Select * from Customers where CustName LIKE '%Concord Elementary School'
Select * from Customers where CustName LIKE 'Concord Elementary School%'
Select * from Customers where CustName LIKE '%Concord Elementary School%'
```

However, a customer noticed that the Ends With and Contains searches weren't working.  (They had recently updated their database with our script that enables Unicode, changing `CHAR` fields to `NVARCHAR` fields....)

As far as I know, these queries worked before the "Unicode Update" which changed field types for many tables.

If I run the above SQL against the database, I get a result for the third and fourth queries.  However, the first and second queries return nothing.

So, I went to the field, copied the data out, pasted it, and notice that the field had spaces at the end -- no doubt the result of the field once being a `CHAR`.  As a result, the above queries fail to provide the desired/expected results.

We have thousands of these queries, so a fix is not clear.

My question then:  What can be done about this to make our application work as expected?

Comment: UPDATE data and use RTRIM on columns that has changed (CHAR -> VARCHAR)

Comment: If you've stored white space at the end of `varchar` there's only really 2 options. Fix the data, or change the query. Both options will require the use of `RTRIM`. Either way, you're going to either have a lot of data or queries to update. Personally, I'd fix the data.

Comment: Ironically (?), if you do `WHERE CustName = 'Concord Elementary School'` rather than `LIKE`, the "exact match" query will work, courtesy of ending spaces not "counting" for comparison purposes. That won't fix things for "ends with", though, and is a weird thing to rely on in general anyway.

Comment: Interestingly, if you use a `varchar` this behaviour doesn't occur. I do have to ask, as well, do you need to use an `nvarchar`, considering your example literal strings are not an `nvarchar`. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dbeff/2)

Comment: @Larnu --- we need the fields to be Unicode capable.

Comment: OK, then, like several of us have recommended, you're going to need to fix your data I'm afraid.  Also, just in case; if that SQL is procedurally generated, then ensure you declare your literal strings as an `nvarchar`. So you need to prefix the string with `N`, for example `N'Concord Elementary School'`. It doesn't matter for the string in your example, but if you had a unicode character in your literal string, then it would be lost.  For example, try `SELECT '۞' AS v, N'۞' AS n;`. Notice that `v` has a value of `'?'`. *۞: random unicode character I found when I googled "Unicode Character"*

Answer (score 7):

I would fix the data:

```
update Customers
    set CustName = ltrim(rtrim(CustName));
```

You may need more complex logic if the "spaces" are not simple spaces.

If you cannot do this (for some reason), you could add a new column:

```
alter customers add custname_cleaned as ( ltrim(rtrim(CustName)) );
```

However, this would require changing all your queries.